# How to change a CKEditor plugin title in the config.js

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a possibility to change the 'title' and/or 'button' property defined in the plugin's `lang.js` file  via the `config.js` file for a specific plugin?

It is the text which is shown in the dialog title/tooltip and I would like to avoid changing it directly inside the `lang.js` file. Or would I have to write the devs for a more fitting translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or would I have to write the devs for a more fitting translation?

If you want to change the translation in CKEditor, the recommended way is joining the Transifex translation team - https://www.transifex.com/ckeditor/ckeditor/

You can change the lang entry like it has been presented below (you can put this code inside `config.js`) but please note **this will not be localized** thus if your CKEditor supports multiple languages it is better to make this change in `lang` file directly.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )    {
    console.log( editor.lang.button );
    editor.lang.button.selectedLabel = 'xyz';
    console.log( editor.lang.button );
});
```